# c# winform app.config "&" char doesn't work in string

Tags: c#, app-config

In my app.config file I want to add param2="&password=" but it doesn't work because of "&" char any idea why ?

```
 <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="API">
          <section name="loginURL" type="System.Configuration.SingleTagSectionHandler"/>
        </sectionGroup>
 </configSections>
 <API>
        <loginURL url="http://test.fr:81/api/sm?" param1="name=" param2="&password="/>
 </API>
```

Comment: Use &amp;   instead

Answer (score 3):

Since `web.config` files are XML, they follow normal XML rules. This means the attributes are XML encoded. To use an `&` sign, you should replace it with `&amp;`

```
 <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="API">
          <section name="loginURL" type="System.Configuration.SingleTagSectionHandler"/>
        </sectionGroup>
 </configSections>
 <API>
        <loginURL url="http://test.fr:81/api/sm?" param1="name=" param2="&amp;password="/>
 </API>
```